# Where is the tag received from MPI_Recv stored in MPI?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

In MPI_Recv, if we receive data using MPI_ANY_TAG, where is the actual value of tag that comes in MPI_ANY_TAG stored? Is it just lost or can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual value of the tag is stored in the `status` argument of `MPI_Recv()`. Abstract from the [MPI standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf), 3.2.5 return status, on page 60 :

> In C, `status` is a structure that contains three fields named
>   `MPI_SOURCE`, `MPI_TAG`, and `MPI_ERROR` ; the structure may contain
>   additional fields. Thus, `status.MPI_SOURCE`, `status.MPI_TAG` and
>   `status.MPI_ERROR` contain the source, tag, and error code,
>   respectively, of the received message.

[Here](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Probe.html) is an example of how to use the `status` argument.

Hence, it's not lost, and you can use it !